# Searchable database of pictures

Tags: file-management, images, database

I need either a Windows or Mac based program that will create a database of images that are searchable. The images can be tagged but will need to be searchable by person's name, year or month or a combination of the 3.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest giving [DigiKam](https://www.digikam.org/) a go, it is a digital photo management suite:

- Free (Libre & FOSS)
- Packages available for Linux, OS-X & Windows or you can compile from source
- Allows you to tag photos and filter on single or multiple tags.
- You can also filter on text, MIME Type & Geolocation.

[image: ScreenShot with Ice]